# TV Miniseries about strange artifacts and a hotel room

Tags: story-identification, tv

This was an American TV series that was aired about 10 years ago.

This series focused on mysterious artifacts with supernatural abilities, i.e. there was a credit card which teleported people after touching.

It was later revealed that all of the artifacts came from certain hotel room. In this room some kind of supernatural "incident" occurred many years ago. As a result, all items in the room acquired supernatural abilities, There was also a one-eyed man who was present in the room when the incident occurred.

Comment: As @Keen pointed out, there is also Warehouse 13 (check it out on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warehouse_13) and on [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1132290/)). I certainly believe that The Lost Room is the answer to your question, and I assume you read the Wikipedia entry before you accepted my answer, but I'm mentioning Warehouse 13 here for completeness. If nothing else, it may give you yet another show to enjoy. :)

Comment: and now there is also warehouse 13's quirky baby brother The Librarians.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is most likely [The Lost Room](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Room)

From the Wikipedia link:

> The Lost Room is a 2006 science fiction television miniseries that aired on the Sci Fi Channel in the United States. The series revolves around the titular room and some of the everyday items from that room which possess unusual powers. The show's protagonist, Joe Miller, is searching for these objects to rescue his daughter, Anna, who has disappeared inside the Room. Once a typical room at a 1960s motel along U.S. Route 66, the Lost Room has existed outside of normal time and space since 1961, when what is referred to only as "the Event" took place.

According to that same Wikipedia link, a comic book continuation of the series has been announced, but is yet to be released.

Comment: See also: Warehouse 13, which shares the same 'everyday objects are magical' portion of the premise.

Comment: @Keen Yes, I know. I had high hopes for it when I first heard about it, but I was quite disappointed. However, it seems I'm in minority, considering the rates on IMDb.

Comment: There were _lots_ of strange objects, leaving to one of my favorite quotes from that series. When the protagonist pointed a gun at someone, and they asked "what does the gun do" - "it fires bullets, really fast".